# Is there a Resharper plugin (or similar) that allows you to find a code path from method A to method B?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, resharper

I have a method in my code, let's call it MethodA, and I know at some point the execution of that method will cause another method, let's call it MethodB, to execute.

I'd like to know what code execution path is taken to get from MethodA to MethodB.

Is there a Resharper plugin (or something else but Resharper is preferred) that does this?

Comment: Can you not just put a breakpoint at the start of MethodA and step into/over the sections of code you are interested in?

Comment: Yes but that would assume I can debug the application. In my case debugging the application is very time consuming. It would be a lot more efficient if there was a plugin that could just show me the relevant paths.

Comment: @Kirk that's perfect man, could you add that as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe `ReSharper | Inspect | Incoming Calls` (while your cursor is within the name of `MethodB` at its declaration) is the closest you're going to get in ReSharper. It works, but you'll have to find "MethodA" in the result yourself.

Answer (score 2):

There is a feature in Visual Studio ( I am not sure which version have that) which allows you to draw sequence diagram of that method. You can use that to find path from method A to another method B

see [Figure 10: Generate Sequence Diagram for a Method](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article890-visual-studio-2010-architecture-features.aspx)